# Download selected data in altair

Tags: python, altair

I have an `altair` plot with multiple selections enabled, like [this](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/interactions.html#multiple-selections). Is there a way to pass the selections outside of `altair`? I'd like to make a button for the user to download only the selected data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is currently no way to access selected data in Python. With some work, you may be able to do it from javascript using the [Vega API](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/), but I'm not aware of any example of this, and related project issues remain open: e.g. [vega/vega-lite#2790](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/2790), [vega/vega-lite#1830](https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/1830).

Answer (score -1):

you may use streamlit lib for this purpose. Here is link to docs about data exploring app https://streamlit.io/docs/tutorial/create_a_data_explorer_app.html .

Comment: This answer does not explain how to extract the selection out of an altair visualization